# PHP Laravel - OrderBy (reverse) and paginate

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am trying everything for an hour to do a simple thing in laravel, and nothing works....

So, I have lots of episodes which should be paginated, but before that those episodes should be orderedBy a has-to-many relationship.

I've tried this, but it didn't work:

```
$result = TheEpisode::where('seriesID', $id)->with(['TheNumbers' => function ($query) {
  return $query->orderBy('episodeNumber', 'desc')->get();
}])->paginate(12);
```

I also tried this:

```
$result = TheEpisode::where('seriesID', $id)->orderBy("TheNumbers.episodeNumber", 'desc')->paginate(12);
```

Does not work either.

## EDIT

```
$result = TheEpisode::where('seriesID', $id)->get()->sortByDesc(function ($item) {
  return $item->TheNumbers->max('episodeNumber');
});
```

This works, and returns 120 episodes in reverse order, now what I need is to paginate it, how do I do that?

Comment: Did you tried orderBy on relation?

Comment: try to move `->get()` after `with` and before `->paginate(12)`

Comment: remove the `->get()` inside relationship source: http://laravel.io/forum/09-14-2014-orderby-on-hasmany-relationship

Comment: @Beginner, I did, doesn't work.

Comment: Check my last edit.

Comment: @Mazarei if i remove the get part, sortByDesc will not work.

Comment: My mistake, I removed the comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
$result = TheEpisode::where('seriesID', $id)->sortByDesc(function ($item) {
    return $item->TheNumbers->max('episodeNumber');
})->paginate(15)->get();
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/pagination

Comment: ->paginate does not work because it should be done before ->get()

Comment: sortbyDesc should be after ->get()